# Process list stream and collect into map/ImmutableMap with only non null values

Tags: java, java-8, guava, collectors

How to process a list of string and collec it into Map or Immutable map only for those whose value is present

```
String anotherParam = "xyz";
Map.Builder<String,String> resultMap = ImmutableMap.builder(..)

 listOfItems.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .distinct()
            .forEach(
                    item -> {
                        final Optional<String> result =     
    getProcessedItem(item,anotherParam);

                        if (result.isPresent()) {

    resultMap.put(item, result.get());
                        }
                    });
        return resultMap.build();
```

Please tell, is there a better way to achieve this via collect?

Comment: Both `listOfItems()` and `getProcessedItem(...)` can yield `null` ?

Comment: list of items can have null String element and  return type for getProcessedItem(..) is Optional<String>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to Apache Commons library you can make use of Pair.class

```
Map<String, String> resultMap = ImmutableMap.copyof(listOfItems()
    .stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .distinct()
    .map(it -> Pair.of(it, getProcessedItem(it,anotherParam))
    .filter(pair -> pair.getValue().isPresent())
    .collect(toMap(Pair::getKey, pair -> pair.getValue().get())))
```

But it's a good practice to make special data classes which describes your mapping item->result more specificly

Here is an example, create class like this:

```
static class ItemResult(){
    public final String item;
    public final Optional<String> result;

    public ItemResult(String item, Optional<String> result){
        this.item = item;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public boolean isPresent(){
        return this.result.isPresent();
    }

    public String getResult(){
        return result.get();
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
Map<String, String> resultMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(listOfItems()
    .stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .distinct()
    .map(it -> new ItemResult(it, getProcessedItem(it,anotherParam))
    .filter(ItemResult::isPresent)
    .collect(toMap(ItemResult::item, ItemResult::getResult)))
```

You can read [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#tuples-for-n--2) why Google gave up the idea of tuples and pairs and don't use them in most cases

If after all you don't want to use any other class you can leverage api of the Optional:

```
Map.Builder<String,String> resultMap = ImmutableMap.builder(..)

listOfItems.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .distinct()
        .forEach(item -> getProcessedItem(item,anotherParam)
                         .ifPresent(result -> resultMap.put(item result));
    return resultMap.build();
```

Comment: Do you see any issue with my implementation ? Is there  away achieve the same without ItemResult and Pair ? Could we also avoid Immutable.copyof ?

Comment: As I can see, there are no critical issues with your implementation but you are writing code as it was in a simple `for` loop and not using abilities of Streams

Comment: @sidss I updated the answer and added example of implementation without ItemResult and Pair

Comment: great it works.. Please tell is it recommended to use externally declared builder ? Which one would you recommend, the one with collect  or this ?

Comment: Both approaches produce equal result, so I think it's a matter of taste and your team code style.

Comment: Why not use Map.Entry instead of Pair, which is totally appropriate in this case?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Map.Entry is an interface, not a class. Of course we can use something like AbstractMap.SimpleEntry but sidss decided not use any other class

Comment: Yes, that was what I had in mind.  So why would you use Pair instead of something built into the JDK that actually suits the use case?

Comment: Actually Pair is just first thing which popped into my mind. IMHO, Map.Entry is more like an internal class and shouldn't be used directly